# Java - Word Count True or False

Tags: java, methods, count, cpu-word

i have a programming task using java...

```
public class CountWords{  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String sentence = "Papa beauty lies in the eyes of beholder";  
    int wordcount = 0;  
      
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length()-1; i++) {  
        if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' ' && Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i+1)) && (i > 0)) {  
            wordcount++;  
        }  
    }  
    wordcount++;
    
    System.out.println("Total number of words: " + wordcount);  
    System.out.println(sentence.startsWith("P"));
}}
```

My question is how can i define the String sentence based on this condition:

1. If more than 3 words, it will be True.
2. If less than 4 words, it becomes False.

Thankyou so much for helping..

Comment: `if (wordCount > 3)`

Comment: Hello welcome to stack overflow!, please be more specific while asking a question.Try to explain it much as you can.This will help you .https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...

```
 /* returns string array of tokens (words in the sentence) after splitting by space */
String[] tokens = sentence.split(" ");

if(tokens.length() > 3) {
  // true
} else {
  // fasle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the steps we should take in order to achieve your goal in a easier way;

1. First , let's count the number of words in your input string via
   count function
2. Call the function by sending our input sentence
3. Function returns number of words Check the number of words for any
   condition you desire

Therefore your code will work better like this;

```
public class CountWords{  

public static void main(String[] args) {  

    String sentence = "Papa beauty lies in the eyes of beholder";
    private bool coniditon;
    int wordcount = count(sentencte);
      

    if (wordcount<4) {
        condition=False;
        }
    else if (wordcount>3) {
        condition=True;
        }

    System.out.println("Total number of words: " + wordcount);  
    System.out.println(sentence.startsWith("P"));

     
  }


public static int count(String sentence){ 

     if(sentence == null || sentence.isEmpty()){ 
        return 0; } 

      String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
      return words.length; }
   }

}
```

Good luck!